# Delete Unique Permission for item level

Tags: sharepoint-online, item-level-permissions

I have a document library with 4,500 documents, half of the documents have unique permissions and don't inherit permission from the document library. What I am trying to achieve is to delete the unique permissions from those documents. Is there any way I can do this with PowerShell?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SharePoint Online: Delete Unique Permissions from a List/Library using PnP PowerShell**

```
#Set Variables
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
$ListName = "Documents"
  
#Connect to PNP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
 
#Get all list items in batches
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 5000
 
#Iterate through each list item
ForEach($ListItem in $ListItems)
{
    #Check if the Item has unique permissions
    $HasUniquePermissions = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $ListItem -Property "HasUniqueRoleAssignments"
    If($HasUniquePermissions)
    {       
        $Msg = "Deleting Unique Permissions on {0} '{1}' at {2} " -f $ListItem.FileSystemObjectType,$ListItem.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"],$ListItem.FieldValues["FileRef"]
        Write-host $Msg
        #Delete unique permissions on the list item
        Set-PnPListItemPermission -List $ListName -Identity $ListItem.ID -InheritPermissions
    }
}
```

**SharePoint Server: Remove unique permissions on List Items**

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 
#Variables for Web URL, List Name
$WebURL ="http://spserver/sites/sitename"
$ListName ="Documents"
 
#Get the list items with Unique permissions
$ListItems = (Get-SPweb $WebURL).lists.TryGetList($ListName).Items | Where {$_.HasUniqueRoleAssignments}
 
# If List Exists with Unique permission
Foreach($ListItem in $ListItems)
 {
      #Reset broken list item inheritance
      $ListItem.ResetRoleInheritance()
      Write-host "Broken Inheritance Reset on List Item:" $ListItem.URL
 }
```